# mCustomScrollBar: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).mCustomScrollBar is not a function on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, ecmascript-6

I am trying to initialise and destroy a mCustomScrollBar scrollbar plugin depending on the window's width (some jquery in an es6 app, traspiled using webpack/babel). However I get an error when resizing the window:

"Uncaught TypeError: $(…).mCustomScrollBar is not a function".

Here is my code:

```
function initCustomScrollbar() {
    var scrollPane = document.querySelector(".scroll-content");
    var scrollPaneInit = $(scrollPane).mCustomScrollbar();

    setTimeout(function () {
        var scrollInnerPane = $(scrollPane).find(".mCustomScrollBox");
        $(scrollInnerPane).height(window.innerHeight + "px");
    }, 500);

    $(window).resize(function () {
        if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
            initCustomScrollbar();
        } else {
            $(scrollPane).mCustomScrollBar('destroy');
        }
    });
}

initCustomScrollbar();
```

Can someone point out where I m going wrong?

Comment: Maybe you are not loading the plugin.

Comment: Its definitely loading, unless i would receive a 404 error...

Comment: Not if you forgot to include the plugin.

Comment: Its definitely loading, when I view source and click the link it loads the minified script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the problem, somehow my subconscious forgot Javascript was case sensitive... the function should read:

```
$(scrollPane).mCustomScrollbar();
```

not

```
$(scrollPane).mCustomScrollBar();
```

smh!!!